# How to create a GIST index on locations within a JSONB array column?

Tags: postgis, spatial-index, indexing

I have a `JSONB` column with an array of locations. I want to do a Postgis GiST index on each of the array items.

For example:

```json
[{
  "location":{
         "type": "Point",
         "coordinates": [
            20.1068,
            45.8061
         ]
      }
}, ...
```

What I've tried is indexing just the first item, because that's what I'm using currently:

```sql
CREATE INDEX "property_location" ON "public"."contracts" USING GIST (st_geomfromgeojson(((properties -> 0) ->> 'location'::text)));
```

When running a query, it doesn't look like it's being used.

```sql
explain analyze select * 
FROM
  contracts
WHERE
  ST_DWithin(
    ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(properties -> 0 -> 'location'),
    ST_GeomFromEWKT(
      'SRID=4326;POINT(19.8398 45.2477)'
    )::geography,
    50
  );
```

Output:

```
Gather  (cost=1000.00..7654358.90 rows=69 width=1014) (actual time=343.863..2555.811 rows=22 loops=1)
  Workers Planned: 2
  Workers Launched: 2
  ->  Parallel Seq Scan on contracts  (cost=0.00..7653352.00 rows=29 width=1014) (actual time=323.943..2523.153 rows=7 loops=3)
"        Filter: st_dwithin((st_geomfromgeojson((((properties -> 0) -> 'location'::text))::text))::geography, '0101000020E6100000492EFF21FDD633400F9C33A2B49F4640'::geography, '50'::double precision, true)"
        Rows Removed by Filter: 230260
Planning Time: 0.176 ms
Execution Time: 2555.851 ms
```

How do I properly create the GiST index?

Ideally on all array items – even though in this example I'm only targeting the first item.

Comment: try adding an index on the jsonb column `CREATE INDEX yourtable_jsonb_idx ON yourtable USING gin (jsonbcolumn);`  Also check this out https://scalegrid.io/blog/using-jsonb-in-postgresql-how-to-effectively-store-index-json-data-in-postgresql/

Comment: Usually PG is pretty picky about using the exact same expression in the query as in the index definition. Try using either `-> 'location'` or `->> 'location'::text` (Eventually this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38777535/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-postgres-sql))

Comment: @JGH is right, the index expression technically differs from the query expression! You may need to expect a higher threshold for index lookup invocation due to the high cost value assigned for that function. Apart from that, you cannot expand set items into an index expression; you will have to dump those geometries into a table.